# Problema al visualizar gráficas en R

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

Hola amgigos tengo el siguiente Df con universidades en el cual tengo el promedio de citas y articulos de algunos docentes que trabaja ahí.
Uno de los problemas que tengo es que la mayoria de las universidades tienen en promedio entre cientos y pocos como miles

```
                                        |Citas |Articulos 
Universidad Federal de Santa Catarina   | 512  | 262
Universidad Federal de São Carlos       | 267  | 112
Universidad Federal de São Joao del Rei | 812  | 200
Universidad Federal de Viçosa           |4458  | 700
Universidad Federal del Rio de Janeiro  |  56  |   5
Universidad Federal Fluminense          | 145  |  12
Universidad Federal Rural de Pernambuco |8967  |1230 
Universidad De Sao Paulo                | 123  |  76
Universidad Juárez Autónoma de Tabasco  |1124  | 222
Universidad Veracruzana                 | 986  | 123
```

Entonces como hay muchos saltos, o sea tienen muchos que están entre los cientos y de pronto uno llega los +4 mil y otro da un salto hasta los casi 9 mil y eso hace que mis cluster queden muy amontonados. No creo que los deba tratar como valores atipicos porque no lo es, no fue un fallo en la captura, solo es que tiene investigadores muy reconocidos por lo que no se me hace justo borrarlos pero sus datos me causan muchos problemas hace que mi grafica quede así ¿hay algun curso de youtube o libro donde expliquen como graficar este tipo de casos?

[image: no deja que se aprecien bien los datos]

Si le pongo una escala en log10 me elimina muchos datos por NAs y me aparece el error

```
Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous x-axis
```

Tambien tengo un problema con los nombres ya que son muy largos como "Universidad Federal Rural de Pernambuco" y al momento de añadirlos para saber donde queda tal universidad solo se ven letras amontonadas, sé que podría cambiarlos manualmente en la columna pero no sé si existe una manera más optima de solucionar esto. Ya que son muchas universidades. O si puedo identificar a cada universidad por puntos de colores

[image: aquí eliminé el valor "atipico" de 9k para que se vea mejor]

Esta es la parte de mi codigo que hace los cluster y las gráficas

```
CitArt <- CitArt %>% remove_rownames %>% column_to_rownames(var="UTrabajo")


    CitasArticulos = scale(CitArt, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
    summary(CitasArticulos)
    CitasArticulos <- as.data.frame(CitasArticulos)
    Universidades <- rownames(CitasArticulos)
    kmclusterU = kmeans(CitasArticulos,centers=3,nstart = 49)
    kmclusterU
    CitasArticulos <- CitasArticulos %>% mutate(cluster = kmclusterU$cluster)
    (g1=ggplot(CitasArticulos, aes(x = Articulos, y = Citas)) +
        geom_point(aes(color=as.factor(cluster)), size=10)+
        geom_text(aes(label = cluster), size = 5) +
        theme_bw() +
        theme(legend.position = "none")+
        labs(title = "Kmenas con k=4")
    )
    fviz_cluster(kmclusterU, CitasArticulos)+ 
      theme_minimal()
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Muy interesante pregunta. Sin embargo, es buena idea que publiques los datos no como una foto sino como un código que los cree o ponerlos en Gitlab o Github y publicar el link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podría sugerirte, por el lado del código `ggplot` "puro", es convertir los valores de citas y artículos a una escala logarítmica, **pero esto va a modificarte sin duda los clusters que se formen**, lo que podría ser beneficioso o no, eso deberías evaluarlo. Dos mejores adicionales podrían ser:

- Hacer un "wrap" de las etiquetas para que ocupen mejor el espacio
- Usar el paquete `ggrepel` que "acomoda" las etiquetas de una forma más legible

Ejemplo:

```
library(ggrepel)

# Todo a log10 y scale
CitArt %>% 
  mutate(Articulos = log10(Articulos),
         Citas = log10(Citas)) %>% 
  scale(center = TRUE, scale = TRUE) -> CitasArticulos

kmclusterU = kmeans(CitasArticulos, centers=3, nstart = 49)

# Agregamos el cluster y rowname a variable
CitasArticulos %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(cluster = kmclusterU$cluster) %>% 
  rownames_to_column("UTrabajo") -> CitasArticulos

ggplot(CitasArticulos, aes(x = Articulos, y = Citas)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=as.factor(cluster)), size=10)+
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = str_wrap(UTrabajo, 10)), 
                   max.iter = Inf, 
                   max.overlaps = Inf,
                   box.padding = 1.5,
                   size = 3) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  labs(title = "Kmenas con k=4")
```

Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otro lado, `fviz_cluster` puede usar `ggrepel`, así:

```
fviz_cluster(kmclusterU, CitasArticulos,
             repel=TRUE)+ 
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudó bastante.